# Kendo Grid with grouping automatically jumping to the first matching element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which groups by name with a checkbox to select or unselect elements based on a payrollid.  A payrollid can appear for multiple names.

A sample of the data would be
1, Fred /
2, Fred /
1, Tom /
1, Mel /
1, Jim /
2, Jim /
2, Joey
…

Now if there are a lot of elements, and I scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on a checkbox to remove the PayrollId 2 for Jim, the grid automatically jumps up to the matching PayrollId 2 for Fred.  It's scrolling / jumping to the first element it finds that matches the PayrollId for the checkbox I selected, but I would like it to stay where it is.

Is there a way to remove this functionality?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post an example of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the  **Navigatable()** property of kendo grid and try..I think it will work